# Formula doesn't recognize cell reference - Dynamic range

Tags: excel

I have a SUMIFS formula with which I am trying to build a dynamic range in order to avoid a circular reference. As it must search and sum through all the range, it must not consider the line where the formula is placed.

Sheet - Example

[image]

So I wrote this formula:

> SUMIFS((C1:ADDRESS(VALUE(ROW(C6))-1;COLUMN(C1));ADDRESS(VALUE(ROW(C6))+1;COLUMN(C1)):ADDRESS(COUNTA(C:C);COLUMN(C1)));(C1:ADDRESS(VALUE(ROW(C6))-1;COLUMN(A1));ADDRESS(VALUE(ROW(C6))+1;COLUMN(A1)):ADDRESS(COUNTA(C:C);COLUMN(A1)));A6;(B1:ADDRESS(VALUE(ROW(C6))-1;COLUMN(B1));ADDRESS(VALUE(ROW(C6))+1;COLUMN(B1)):ADDRESS(COUNTA(C:C);COLUMN(B1)));"X")

However, after the sum_range it doesn't recognize the cell references. It remains "black". I tried another formula with OFFSET but got the same issue.

Any ideia what is going on?

A quick note, I need a dynamic range because there might be new lines inserted afterwards or people might apply filters, so I cannot use a normal reference.

Comment: My example is 95% precise. Consider the formula is at "Value" column and the value is empty. That is how my actual workboo is. However, I don't think it would influence the issue on the cell references.

Comment: You will not avoid circular references if you are trying to sum the same column in which the formula is placed just by not including the actual cell.  The sum of row 2 depend on the value in row 7 and the value in row 7 depends on the value in row 2, so it is circular.

Comment: If I had only one condition, which is easier to illustrate, my formula should express "Sum every value in column C except the line if the value on column A except the line is equal to the line's coilumn A. I might review the fomula but still cannot get why it doesn't recognize the cells on the formula.

Comment: if you put the formula in another column then yes, we can make it work, but trying to put the formula in the same column as the retun of the SUMIFS will cause a circular formula.

Comment: I see. The necessity to be in the same column is due the output of all this: a pivot chart. I will have to calculate this in another cell and return to the cell I want for the pivot chart. I will try this and check if the "not recognizing a cell" still occurs...

Comment: It will, SUMIFS does not like disjointed ranges, so use two, one for above and one for below.  And avoid Volatile functions ADDRESS/INDIRECT/OFFSET.  to do it with ADDRESS you would need to incorporate INDIRECT.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the formula in the same column as the range to sum, in this case it would cause a circular reference.

Use INDEX and two SUMIFS, SUMIFS does not like disjointed ranges and ADDRESS/OFFSET/INDIRECT are volatile:

```
=SUMIFS($C$1:INDEX(C:C;ROW()-1);$A$1:INDEX(A:A;ROW()-1);A2;$B$1:INDEX(B:B;ROW()-1);B2)+SUMIFS(INDEX(C:C;ROW()+1):INDEX(C:C;MATCH(1E+99;C:C));INDEX(A:A;ROW()+1):INDEX(A:A;MATCH(1E+99;C:C));A2;INDEX(B:B;ROW()+1):INDEX(B:B;MATCH(1E+99;C:C));B2)
```

[image]